# Use default browser messages when validating form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am trying to do jquery form validation with messages but I want the error message to show up in the browsers default tooltips such as when you use the type email or add required to an input like this:

```
<input type="email" class="email" id='email' name='email' placeholder="EMAIL" required>
```

I do not want to install a third party tooltip library, I just want to use the default browser's system.

Here is Chrome:
[image]

Here is Safari for the same form:
[image]

Those messages are not created by jquery, only by the browser. Is there a way I can redirect my validate messages to the system the browser uses? Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login-form').validate({
        rules: {
            login_email: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7
            },
            login_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        messages: {
            login_email: {
                required: "Email is required to login",
                minlength: "Email must contain at least {0} characters"
            },
            login_password: {
                required: "A password is required to login",
                minlength: "Password must contain at least {0} characters"
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I added title='you need to do this' to the email element and it did nothing.

Comment: Take a look at html5 form validation, specifically the "customized error messages" secrtion https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Customized_error_messages

Comment: @freedomn-m All I see at that jsfiddle is an input. I never see 'do it' anywhere.

Comment: @freedomn-m mac osx mojave Chrome most up to date version. The other one is safari. Only 3rd party is jquery from the code.jquery cdn. Correct, it is not shown all the time, only when you leave the input for the next field. I wanted to fire them off on submit with jquery validate. I am abandoning this now, I am just going to use the default with jquery and use errorLabelContainer.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, I'll remove my comments as they've not helped - hopefully someone else will pick it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I am trying to do jquery form validation with messages but I want the error message to show up in the browsers default tooltips..*.

**Impossible**.

When using the jQuery Validate plugin, the browser's HTML5 validation is disabled for obvious reasons.

> *I do not want to install a third party tooltip library, I just want to use the default browser's system.*

**You can not**.

jQuery Validate automatically disables HTML5 validation.  Either you use jQuery Validate with or without popup tooltips via your own code or plugin, OR you use HTML5 validation as provided by the browser.  You cannot do both.

Comment: Ultimatly this was what I found out. I ended up using jquery Validate and position the error messages where I wanted them.